# What is the best knife/sharpener setup for an active cook?

Tags: knives, sharpening

There are several posts that get close to this but I am looking for a specific knife(ves)/sharpener(s) combo(s) that can be used routinely and that work(s) well.  My opinion is in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/840/how-many-ceramic-knives-do-i-want/1051#1051).

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the product in your linked post is an actual *sharpener* or if they're just as confused as everyone else about the difference between *sharpening* and *honing*.  My guess is the latter.

Comment: No, they are certainly not confused.  These are great products and are exactly what they claim them to be.  You may be confused between actually sharpening a low quality knife and a high quality knife.  The below answers do this exact question justice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using cheap knives (which you suggest to the answer you linked to, and I admit, I have quite a few), feel free to sharpen them yourself ... I have both a stick-style diamond dust sharpener, and a set of whet stones.

But I don't sharpen my good kitchen knives myself, and I tend to go a few years between sharpenings (but I also have two chef knives and a santuko, which get the majority of the use, but it's spread across three of 'em, so they likely don't get as much wear if I only had one) ... but I agree with @hobodave -- I hone 'em, but I'm not going to sharpen them myself.

Answer (score 10):

If you have top quality knives, I generally discourage the use of any do-it-yourself sharpeners.  I take my knives yearly to a professional knife sharpener who puts that amazing 17 degree edge back on my Shun knives.

In between sharpening you should be using a quality honing steel *every* time you use your knife.

Additionally, your knives shouldn't need *routine* sharpening. Unless you intend routine to mean every 6-18 months. If you're sharpening knives more frequently than that, **you're doing it wrong**. From what I've seen the quality sharpeners on the  market are just too expensive to justify their space in my kitchen. Maybe if I charged friends for sharpening services?

Comment: 17 degrees is a very obtuse edge to have on a shun (unless you are talking the softer Wasabi series). And some japanese knife types just need to be very sharp to work, and would be sharpened *daily* in professional use, and probably monthly or after heavy use in a hobbyist kitchen.

Answer (score 2):

The best sharpener is the old italian man in a van who comes by on Saturday morning ringing his bell.

If you have good knives, don't try to sharpen them yourself.  You need a grinder with the exactly right stone on it, and you need to have destroyed a couple hundred practice blades before you get the technique right.

I get my knives sharpened every 18-24 months, and steel them about 15 strokes per side before use.

Comment: A "grinder" (as in, a powered device) is rarely needed, and indeed not recommendable for non-professionals - even many professionals use them wrongly and damage knives.