# Technical name for a manual food processor

Tags: blender, food-processing

I am looking to buy a food processor to do very small batches of fruit and vegetables.
Very basic, very cheap....and i am looking for something manual(not electricity).
Is there a manual version existing?
What is it called?

Comment: A search on amazon for "manual food processor" brings back a number of results for crank powered twin spinning blade style processor/chopper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is 'chopper'.  [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002FCG46) and [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002YTFS2) for example.

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HFR2MS), a draw string powered chopper, is an interesting idea as well - I have difficultly believing it can produce enough force though.

And there's the [rotating handle, crank kind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CM975O).

You've got options.

Or even more basic, 'knife' ;)

Comment: Thanks. My knife skills are not that good. the links that you posted...it does not say if it is manual or electricity operated. What do you think?

Comment: Its manual, you tap down on it and it cuts and rotates the blade coming up.  Then the next time it cuts and rotates, then cuts and rotates, etc...

Comment: Electric version here: http://www.amazon.com/Black-Decker-EHC650-2-Speed-Chopper/dp/B00005MF97

Comment: Considering 'honing' ;) your knife skills though.  Food choppers have their place but they get dull and some can be a pain to clean.

Comment: Really not complete without: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWRyj5cHIQA

Answer (score 3):

Mandoline. Depending on what model you get it can slice, dice, grate, and chip!

US$20 will get you a basic one. The better ones are often a long running brand with replaceable blades

See [What to look for in a mandoline?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15273/what-to-look-for-in-a-mandoline)